# update data with dialog dropdownlist selected value change

Tags: jquery, asp.net, gridview

i am updating gridview record with jquery dialog problem is that i am facing is when dropdownlist value comes its always select first value of dropdown

```
$("[id*=ddlCategory]").val(categoryName);
        $("[id*=txtName]").val(surveyName);
        $("#dialog").dialog({
            title: "jQuery Show Gridview Row Details in Popup",
            width: 300,
            height: 250,
            modal: true,
            buttons: {
                Close: function() {
                    $(this).dialog('close');
                }

            }
      });
```

in textbox gridview record text is showing correct but in dropdown its always select first record . i am wondering how  to selected text change according to text.

Comment: how you are selecting dropdown value ?, are u using DropDown.SelectedItem ?

Comment: i have bind my dropdownlist from my database value

Comment: Yeah thats right, how you are selecting the value in code ?, have u used any asp.net code ?

Comment: hi i did got what i wants with this code 
        $("[id*=ddlCategory] option:selected").text(categoryName); but its display duplicate of selected value

Comment: is it binding twice ?

Comment: no basically jquery pick value from html and makes as selection at the top of it but actual value is middle of my binding